# opensource project + suggestions for starting + rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, open-source, project-management

I'm thinking of developing an open source project management tool using rails3. (I know there are many, but what I want is to roll out of my own so that i can learn). But before that I have some questions to clarify..

please give your suggestions on followings

1 - What is the best way to release these kind of a project
    1 - As a default rails appliation

```
2 - As a ruby gem (if so how can I do it)
```

2 - How can make upgrades available for existing users
    1 - do they need to download the whole project and replacing their existing one

```
2 - can I modularize my updates and ask users to download and install only the features they want 

     Ex: My tool might have a separate module for bills and only the users who wants billing can only download and install that module (If you what is the best way to do it)
```

thanks in advance

cheers

sameera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is -- it depends.

If this is basically an application, and does not include a lot of unique functionality that would be useful separate from the application, then it should simply be an application.  i would place it in a GIT repository, so that users can upgrade simply by typing `git pull` and then running `rake db:migrate` to incorporate any new database changes.

If all or most of the application can be incorporated into someone else's existing application as an enhancement or extension, then that portion would be especially nice to package as a gem -- eventually.

Initially, I would not set out to create the application as a main app with optional modules.  You should always try to keep concerns well separated within your design, and that would make such a separation relatively painless to do later, but first get the thing working before adding concerns that will cost more time and delay the satisfaction of releasing something people can use and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really say as I don't do much Ruby.  But something worth you looking at is Google's App Engine and developing your project on there as a gem:

http://code.google.com/p/appengine-jruby/

Comment: Hi @Gonzalez, I will have a look

Answer (score 0):

You could develop the software as a service and offer it to your users (even maybe customers) on your hosting. That way you own the code, provide service and don't have to deal with user installations.

Comment: sure.. that is my ultimate goal.. :D